# AWS Step Function How can I get an integer using dynamodb:getItem?

Tags: aws-step-functions

In my step function execution input I have some resources defined like this:

```json
    "resource_parameters": {
      "Item": {
        "memory": {
          "N": "40"
        }
      } ...
```

I should mention that the above is the response from a call to DynamoDb (value are stored as numbers) using `"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem",`
I would like to use the value "40" in my step function definition like this:

```json
"Memory.$": "$.resource_parameters.Item.memory.N"
```

However I get an error: The Parameters could not be used to start the Task: [The value for the field 'Memory' must be an INTEGER]"

How can I specify an integer from a input variable?

Comment: It seems that with the version of step function/batch that I am using this is not possible. My workaround was to all a lambda that converts strings to integers.

Answer (score 1):

The `StringToJson` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate) will convert a string input to a number:

```js
"Memory.$": "States.StringToJson($.resource_parameters.Item.memory.N)" // "40" -> 40
```